# Jumping forward or backward in a .mp4 file takes a long time in VLC

Tags: encoding, mp4, obs, vlc

Recently, I randomly played around a bit with the video encoder settings of my OBS Studio (29.1.2) and recorded a video playing in the browser. In this particular video (recorded with some settings I cannot recall), it takes VLC a lot of time to jump forward or backward in time. Can someone please explain why? Codec and encoder screenshots attached.
[image]
[image]